# What is a good way to render a site or portions of a site into a desktop gadget/widget?

Tags: website, desktop-gadget

I guess a better way to ask [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/146292/i-need-a-way-to-read-web-feeds-that-meets-the-following-requirements) (or an alternative to it, in my case) would be to first ask what a good way to do *this* would be, instead.  Namely, I want to have a gadget on my desktop (not just in a browser window) with options such as overlaying on top of other windows, offline caching, etc. that is dedicated expressly to a given website (no browsing functions or menus).

Be even more awesome if I could indicate a specific physical part of the website to show in the gadget.  Someone's probably got to have a scraper for doing that...

Comment: In Windows 98 you can just active "Active Desktop", or put another way, what platform are we talking about?

Comment: Vista or later.  But active desktop couldn't overlay, as I recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Bubbles may do what you want: http://bubbleshq.com/features. I'm not sure it will support offline caching unless the web app itself does. It has an API for extending/modifying sites, so if you don't mind delving into their api ( http://bubbleshq.com/api ) you can limit it to only a specific part of the website AFAICT.